# maui android webview not getting site cookies

Tags: android, cookies, webview, maui

I'm writing a cross platform MAUI app. After authentication the user is redirected to the login page because the cookie collection is empty. If I use a browser everything works fine, but using the WebView the cookie CookieManager cookie collection and the WebView Cookie collection is empty, unless I manually add a cookie, but it does not pick up the site/domain cookies.

in the MainPage:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var Url = _host + "/DriverPortal/DriverHome";
    Browser.Cookies = new CookieContainer();  
    Browser.Source = Url; 

            try
            {
                Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
                {
#if ANDROID
                    var cm = Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance;
                    cm.SetAcceptCookie(true);
                    cm.SetAcceptThirdPartyCookies(handler.PlatformView, true);                         
                    handler.PlatformView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;                   
                    Browser.Cookies.Add(new Cookie(){ Name="ChocChip", Expires=DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Value="yum", Domain=_host, Path="/" });
#endif

                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

in OnNavigating() I set a breakpoint and see that the only cookie found is the "ChocChip" cookie from above.

Previously at this spot I could see the "ASPXAUTH" authentication cookie and another cookie that I added in the action code.

Recently it just stopped pulling those cookies in to the Webview and CookieManager. I don't know what I changed that could have possible affected this.